# AMP: How to submit form on change event with condition

Tags: form-submit, onchange, amp-html, google-amp

I have couple linked dropdowns and want to prevent form submit on change event if linked dropdown is empty.

```
<form id="foo">
    <select name="first" on="change:AMP.setState({settings: {first: event.value}}),foo.submit" >
        ...
    </select>

    <select name="second" on="change:AMP.setState({settings: {second: event.value}}),foo.submit" >
        <option value=0> Please select </option>
        ...
    </select>

</form>
```

Can i check state and then submit form if the value is appropriate? Something like:

```
<select name="first" on="change:AMP.setState({settings: {first: event.value}}),settings.second ? foo.submit : nothing to do" >
```

for the first dropdown to avoid form submit when I select new value, because second not welected yet.

Tried make it with validation, but it not work with dropdown, input works fine.

```
            <input type="text"
                   id="show-first-on-submit-name"
                   name="name"
                   placeholder="Digit..."
                   required
                   on="change:AMP.setState({settings: {testing: event.value}}),requirements-form.submit"
                   pattern="^([1-9][0-9]*)$">
            <span visible-when-invalid="valueMissing"
                  validation-for="show-first-on-submit-name"></span>
            <span visible-when-invalid="patternMismatch"
                  validation-for="show-first-on-submit-name">
              Please enter not '0'
            </span>

            <select name="purpose"
                    id="purpose"
                    pattern="^([1-9][0-9]*)$"
                    required
                    on="change:AMP.setState({settings: {purpose: event.value}}),requirements-form.submit">
                <option value="0">Please select</option>
                <option value="1">One</option>
            </select>
            <span visible-when-invalid="valueMissing"
                  validation-for="purpose">missing</span>
            <span visible-when-invalid="patternMismatch"
                  validation-for="purpose">wrong</span>
```

Comment: You can try [Form Custom Validation](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/): how-first-on-submit, show-all-on-submit or else as-you-go.

Comment: validation works fine for input but not work for select.

Answer (score 0):

Validating form by converting input status into an `amp-state` object and checking them when change event occurs is a little circuitous.

In my opinion it would be more easier to use [HTML5 Form validation API](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api) (AMP use it as well) to handle input validation works. All you need to do is add `required` attribute to your `<select>` element and remove `onChange` validation logic.

Here is a simple example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AMP Page</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="self.html" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
  <style amp-custom>
    h1 {
      margin: 1rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form target="_blank" action="/">
    <select name="tier1" required>
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="opt1">tier1 - opt1</option>
      <option value="opt2">tier1 - opt2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="tier2" required>
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="opt1">tier2 - opt1</option>
      <option value="opt2">tier2 - opt2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
    </html>
```

Example screenshot:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but logic with the reloading of the page after clicking the submit button, not for my case